# Lg G3 random reboots while it is connected to wifi or data connection

Tags: wi-fi, 5.0-lollipop, reboot, mobile-data, lg-g3

As soon as I toggle wifi or data , my LG G3 is getting restarted .
I tried factory reset
I tried different rom (everything lolipop 5.0)
I restored to a working backup I had about 3 months before. 
The problem is not going.

EDIT : attaching logs from CATLOG

```
   09-11 09:06:22.110 D/WearableBluetooth( 6796):   at com.google.android.gsf.f.c(SourceFile:107)
    09-11 09:06:22.110 D/WearableBluetooth( 6796):  at com.google.android.gsf.f.a(SourceFile:121)
    09-11 09:06:22.110 D/WearableBluetooth( 6796):  at com.google.android.gsf.f.a(SourceFile:216)
    09-11 09:06:22.110 D/WearableBluetooth( 6796):  at com.google.android.gms.common.b.m.a(SourceFile:336)
    09-11 09:06:22.110 D/WearableBluetooth( 6796):  at com.google.android.gms.common.b.g.a(SourceFile:231)
    09-11 09:06:22.110 D/WearableBluetooth( 6796):  at com.google.android.gms.common.b.e.c(SourceFile:200)
    09-11 09:06:22.110 D/WearableBluetooth( 6796):  at com.google.android.gms.common.b.e.d(SourceFile:211)
    09-11 09:06:22.110 D/WearableBluetooth( 6796):  at com.google.android.gms.wearable.node.eg.e(SourceFile:1919)
    09-11 09:06:22.110 D/WearableBluetooth( 6796):  at com.google.android.gms.wearable.node.eg.a(SourceFile:1771)
    09-11 09:06:22.110 D/WearableBluetooth( 6796):  at com.google.android.gms.wearable.node.eg.a(SourceFile:747)
    09-11 09:06:22.110 D/WearableBluetooth( 6796):  at com.google.android.gms.wearable.node.eg.a(SourceFile:707)
    09-11 09:06:22.110 D/WearableBluetooth( 6796):  at com.google.android.gms.wearable.node.gb.e(SourceFile:233)
    09-11 09:06:22.110 D/WearableBluetooth( 6796):  at com.google.android.gms.wearable.node.gb.a(SourceFile:185)
    09-11 09:06:22.110 D/WearableBluetooth( 6796):  at com.google.android.gms.wearable.node.gb.a(SourceFile:169)
    09-11 09:06:22.110 D/WearableBluetooth( 6796):  at com.google.android.gms.wearable.node.hl.b(SourceFile:420)
    09-11 09:06:22.110 D/WearableBluetooth( 6796):  at com.google.android.gms.wearable.node.hl.a(SourceFile:245)
    09-11 09:06:22.110 D/WearableBluetooth( 6796):  at com.google.android.gms.wearable.node.bluetooth.d.run(SourceFile:112)
    09-11 09:06:22.110 W/WearableConn( 6796): Unexpected runtime exception, error: attempting to read gservices without permission: Neither user 10023 nor current process has com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES.
    09-11 09:06:22.110 E/AndroidRuntime( 6796): FATAL EXCEPTION: WearableAppLogger
    09-11 09:06:22.110 E/AndroidRuntime( 6796): Process: com.google.android.gms.wearable, PID: 6796
    09-11 09:06:22.110 E/AndroidRuntime( 6796): java.lang.RuntimeException: Package manager has died
    09-11 09:06:22.110 E/AndroidRuntime( 6796):     at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getPackageInfo(ApplicationPackageManager.java:112)
    09-11 09:06:22.110 E/AndroidRuntime( 6796):     at com.google.android.gms.playlog.b.<init>(SourceFile:237)
    09-11 09:06:22.110 E/AndroidRuntime( 6796):     at com.google.android.gms.playlog.a.<init>(SourceFile:56)
    09-11 09:06:22.110 E/AndroidRuntime( 6796):     at com.google.android.gms.playlog.a.<init>(SourceFile:39)
    09-11 09:06:22.110 E/AndroidRuntime( 6796):     at com.google.android.gms.playlog.a.<init>(SourceFile:35)
    09-11 09:06:22.110 E/AndroidRuntime( 6796):     at com.google.android.gms.wearable.d.c.handleMessage(SourceFile:91)
    09-11 09:06:22.110 E/AndroidRuntime( 6796):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    09-11 09:06:22.110 E/AndroidRuntime( 6796):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    09-11 09:06:22.110 E/AndroidRuntime( 6796):     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
    09-11 09:06:22.110 E/AndroidRuntime( 6796): Caused by: android.os.DeadObjectException
    09-11 09:06:22.110 E/AndroidRuntime( 6796):     at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
    09-11 09:06:22.110 E/AndroidRuntime( 6796):     at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:496)
    09-11 09:06:22.110 E/AndroidRuntime( 6796):     at android.content.pm.IPackageManager$Stub$Proxy.getPackageInfo(IPackageManager.java:1876)
    09-11 09:06:22.110 E/AndroidRuntime( 6796):     at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getPackageInfo(ApplicationPackageManager.java:107)
    09-11 09:06:22.110 E/AndroidRuntime( 6796):     ... 8 more
    09-11 09:06:22.111 E/wearable( 6796): Unexpected exception in reader or writer:
    09-11 09:06:22.111 E/wearable( 6796): java.lang.SecurityException: attempting to read gservices without permission: Neither user 10023 nor current process has com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES.
    09-11 09:06:22.111 E/wearable( 6796):   at android.app.ContextImpl.enforce(ContextImpl.java:1943)
    09-11 09:06:22.111 E/wearable( 6796):   at android.app.ContextImpl.enforceCallingOrSelfPermission(ContextImpl.java:1972)
    09-11 09:06:22.111 E/wearable( 6796):   at android.content.ContextWrapper.enforceCallingOrSelfPermission(ContextWrapper.java:606)
    09-11 09:06:22.111 E/wearable( 6796):   at com.google.android.gsf.f.c(SourceFile:107)
    09-11 09:06:22.111 E/wearable( 6796):   at com.google.android.gsf.f.a(SourceFile:121)
    09-11 09:06:22.111 E/wearable( 6796):   at com.google.android.gsf.f.a(SourceFile:216)
    09-11 09:06:22.111 E/wearable( 6796):   at com.google.android.gms.common.b.m.a(SourceFile:336)
    09-11 09:06:22.111 E/wearable( 6796):   at com.google.android.gms.common.b.g.a(SourceFile:231)
    09-11 09:06:22.111 E/wearable( 6796):   at com.google.android.gms.common.b.e.c(SourceFile:200)
    09-11 09:06:22.111 E/wearable( 6796):   at com.google.android.gms.wearable.node.ho.a(SourceFile:807)
    09-11 09:06:22.111 E/wearable( 6796):   at com.google.android.gms.wearable.node.hr.a(SourceFile:168)
    09-11 09:06:22.111 E/wearable( 6796):   at com.google.android.gms.wearable.node.fn.a(SourceFile:234)
    09-11 09:06:22.111 E/wearable( 6796):   at com.google.android.gms.wearable.node.fn.c(SourceFile:142)
    09-11 09:06:22.111 E/wearable( 6796):   at com.google.android.gms.wearable.node.fn.call(SourceFile:33)
    09-11 09:06:22.111 E/wearable( 6796):   at com.google.android.gms.wearable.node.hm.a(SourceFile:548)
    09-11 09:06:22.111 E/wearable( 6796):   at com.google.android.gms.wearable.node.hm.call(SourceFile:532)
    09-11 09:06:22.111 E/wearable( 6796):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
    09-11 09:06:22.111 E/wearable( 6796):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
    09-11 09:06:22.111 E/wearable( 6796):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
    09-11 09:06:22.111 E/wearable( 6796):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
    09-11 09:06:22.118 E/AndroidRuntime( 6796): Error reporting crash
    09-11 09:06:22.118 E/AndroidRuntime( 6796): android.os.DeadObjectException
    09-11 09:06:22.118 E/AndroidRuntime( 6796):     at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
    09-11 09:06:22.118 E/AndroidRuntime( 6796):     at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:496)
    09-11 09:06:22.118 E/AndroidRuntime( 6796):     at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.handleApplicationCrash(ActivityManagerNative.java:4225)
    09-11 09:06:22.118 E/AndroidRuntime( 6796):     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler.uncaughtException(RuntimeInit.java:92)
    09-11 09:06:22.118 E/AndroidRuntime( 6796):     at com.google.android.gms.common.app.d.uncaughtException(SourceFile:54)
    09-11 09:06:22.118 E/AndroidRuntime( 6796):     at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:693)
    09-11 09:06:22.118 E/AndroidRuntime( 6796):     at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:690)
    09-11 09:06:22.118 I/Process ( 6796): Sending signal. PID: 6796 SIG: 9
    09-11 09:06:22.123 I/ThermalEngine(  331): Sensor:tsens_tz_sensor8:69000 mC
    09-11 09:06:22.123 I/ThermalEngine(  331): Sensor:tsens_tz_sensor7:74000 mC
    09-11 09:06:22.123 I/ThermalEngine(  331): Sensor:tsens_tz_sensor6:70000 mC
    09-11 09:06:22.123 I/ThermalEngine(  331): Sensor:tsens_tz_sensor5:73000 mC
    09-11 09:06:22.188 I/ThermalEngine(  331): Sensor:tsens_tz_sensor8:69000 mC
    09-11 09:06:22.188 I/ThermalEngine(  331): Sensor:tsens_tz_sensor7:75000 mC
    09-11 09:06:22.188 I/ThermalEngine(  331): Sensor:tsens_tz_sensor6:70000 mC
    09-11 09:06:22.188 I/ThermalEngine(  331): Sensor:tsens_tz_sensor5:71000 mC
    09-11 09:06:22.253 I/ThermalEngine(  331): Sensor:tsens_tz_sensor8:69000 mC
    09-11 09:06:22.253 I/ThermalEngine(  331): Sensor:tsens_tz_sensor7:72000 mC
    09-11 09:06:22.253 I/ThermalEngine(  331): Sensor:tsens_tz_sensor6:69000 mC
    09-11 09:06:22.253 I/ThermalEngine(  331): Sensor:tsens_tz_sensor5:70000 mC
    09-11 09:06:22.319 I/ThermalEngine(  331): Sensor:tsens_tz_sensor8:75000 mC
    09-11 09:06:22.319 I/ThermalEngine(  331): Sensor:tsens_tz_sensor7:70000 mC
    09-11 09:06:22.319 I/ThermalEngine(  331): Sensor:tsens_tz_sensor6:70000 mC
    09-11 09:06:22.319 I/ThermalEngine(  331): Sensor:tsens_tz_sensor5:73000 mC
    09-11 09:06:22.337 E/MusicWearableListener(  354): GoogleApiClient suspended: 1
    09-11 09:06:22.384 I/ThermalEngine(  331): Sensor:tsens_tz_sensor8:73000 mC
    09-11 09:06:22.384 I/ThermalEngine(  331): Sensor:tsens_tz_sensor7:70000 mC
    09-11 09:06:22.384 I/ThermalEngine(  331): Sensor:tsens_tz_sensor6:74000 mC
    09-11 09:06:22.384 I/ThermalEngine(  331): Sensor:tsens_tz_sensor5:76000 mC
    09-11 09:06:22.384 I/ThermalEngine(  331): ACTION: CPU - Setting CPU[0] to 2726400
    09-11 09:06:22.384 I/ThermalEngine(  331): ACTION: CPU - Setting CPU[1] to 2726400
    09-11 09:06:22.384 I/ThermalEngine(  331): ACTION: CPU - Setting CPU[2] to 2726400
    09-11 09:06:22.384 I/ThermalEngine(  331): ACTION: CPU - Setting CPU[3] to 2726400
    09-11 09:06:22.422 D/libEGL  ( 3739): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_adreno.so
    09-11 09:06:22.424 D/libEGL  ( 3739): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_adreno.so
    09-11 09:06:22.427 E/BufferQueueProducer(  292): [StatusBar] dequeueBuffer: BufferQueue has been abandoned
    09-11 09:06:22.427 W/Adreno-EGLSUB( 5737): <DequeueBuffer:720>: dequeue native buffer fail: No such device, buffer=0x0, handle=0x0
    09-11 09:06:22.427 E/BufferQueueProducer(  292): [StatusBar] dequeueBuffer: BufferQueue has been abandoned
    09-11 09:06:22.427 W/Adreno-EGLSUB( 5737): <DequeueBuffer:720>: dequeue native buffer fail: No such device, buffer=0x0, handle=0x0
    09-11 09:06:22.427 W/Adreno-EGL( 5737): <qeglDrvAPI_eglSwapBuffers:3702>: EGL_BAD_SURFACE
    09-11 09:06:22.427 W/OpenGLRenderer( 5737): swapBuffers encountered EGL_BAD_SURFACE on 0xaed29140, halting rendering...
    09-11 09:06:22.441 D/libEGL  ( 3739): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so
    09-11 09:06:22.449 I/ThermalEngine(  331): Sensor:tsens_tz_sensor8:74000 mC
    09-11 09:06:22.449 I/ThermalEngine(  331): Sensor:tsens_tz_sensor7:70000 mC
    09-11 09:06:22.449 I/ThermalEngine(  331): Sensor:tsens_tz_sensor6:72000 mC
    09-11 09:06:22.449 I/ThermalEngine(  331): Sensor:tsens_tz_sensor5:73000 mC
    09-11 09:06:22.449 I/ThermalEngine(  331): ACTION: CPU - Setting CPU[0] to 2880000
    09-11 09:06:22.449 I/ThermalEngine(  331): ACTION: CPU - Setting CPU[1] to 2880000
    09-11 09:06:22.449 I/ThermalEngine(  331): ACTION: CPU - Setting CPU[2] to 2880000
    09-11 09:06:22.449 I/ThermalEngine(  331): ACTION: CPU - Setting CPU[3] to 2880000
    09-11 09:06:22.450 I/Adreno-EGL( 3739): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:410>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: Nondeterministic_AU_msm8974_LA.BF.1.1.1_RB1__release_AU ()
    09-11 09:06:22.450 I/Adreno-EGL( 3739): OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.25.03.00
    09-11 09:06:22.450 I/Adreno-EGL( 3739): Build Date: 12/11/14 Thu
    09-11 09:06:22.450 I/Adreno-EGL( 3739): Local Branch: mybranch6275889
    09-11 09:06:22.450 I/Adreno-EGL( 3739): Remote Branch: quic/LA.BF.1.1_rb1.16
    09-11 09:06:22.450 I/Adreno-EGL( 3739): Local Patches: NONE
    09-11 09:06:22.450 I/Adreno-EGL( 3739): Reconstruct Branch: NOTHING
    09-11 09:06:22.473 D/AndroidRuntime( 6138): Shutting down VM
    09-11 09:06:22.480 E/AndroidRuntime( 6138): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    09-11 09:06:22.480 E/AndroidRuntime( 6138): Process: com.android.phone, PID: 6138
    09-11 09:06:22.480 E/AndroidRuntime( 6138): java.lang.RuntimeException: android.os.DeadObjectException
    09-11 09:06:22.480 E/AndroidRuntime( 6138):     at android.net.TrafficStats.getMobileIfaces(TrafficStats.java:624)
    09-11 09:06:22.480 E/AndroidRuntime( 6138):     at android.net.TrafficStats.getMobileTcpTxPackets(TrafficStats.java:368)
    09-11 09:06:22.480 E/AndroidRuntime( 6138):     at com.android.internal.telephony.dataconnection.DcTrackerBase$TxRxSum.updateTxRxSum(DcTrackerBase.java:498)
    09-11 09:06:22.480 E/AndroidRuntime( 6138):     at com.android.internal.telephony.dataconnection.DcTrackerBase.updateDataActivity(DcTrackerBase.java:1538)
    09-11 09:06:22.480 E/AndroidRuntime( 6138):     at com.android.internal.telephony.dataconnection.DcTrackerBase$3.run(DcTrackerBase.java:375)
    09-11 09:06:22.480 E/AndroidRuntime( 6138):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    09-11 09:06:22.480 E/AndroidRuntime( 6138):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    09-11 09:06:22.480 E/AndroidRuntime( 6138):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    09-11 09:06:22.480 E/AndroidRuntime( 6138):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5374)
    09-11 09:06:22.480 E/AndroidRuntime( 6138):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    09-11 09:06:22.480 E/AndroidRuntime( 6138):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    09-11 09:06:22.480 E/AndroidRuntime( 6138):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:911)
    09-11 09:06:22.480 E/AndroidRuntime( 6138):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
    09-11 09:06:22.480 E/AndroidRuntime( 6138): Caused by: android.os.DeadObjectException
    09-11 09:06:22.480 E/AndroidRuntime( 6138):     at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
    09-11 09:06:22.480 E/AndroidRuntime( 6138):     at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:496)
    09-11 09:06:22.480 E/AndroidRuntime( 6138):     at android.net.INetworkStatsService$Stub$Proxy.getMobileIfaces(INetworkStatsService.java:239)
    09-11 09:06:22.480 E/AndroidRuntime( 6138):     at android.net.TrafficStats.getMobileIfaces(TrafficStats.java:622)
    09-11 09:06:22.480 E/AndroidRuntime( 6138):     ... 12 more
    09-11 09:06:22.480 E/AndroidRuntime( 6138): Error reporting crash
    09-11 09:06:22.480 E/AndroidRuntime( 6138): android.os.DeadObjectException
    09-11 09:06:22.480 E/AndroidRuntime( 6138):     at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
    09-11 09:06:22.480 E/AndroidRuntime( 6138):     at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:496)
    09-11 09:06:22.480 E/AndroidRuntime( 6138):     at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.handleApplicationCrash(ActivityManagerNative.java:4225)
    09-11 09:06:22.480 E/AndroidRuntime( 6138):     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler.uncaughtException(RuntimeInit.java:92)
    09-11 09:06:22.480 E/AndroidRuntime( 6138):     at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:693)
    09-11 09:06:22.480 E/AndroidRuntime( 6138):     at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:690)
    09-11 09:06:22.480 I/Process ( 6138): Sending signal. PID: 6138 SIG: 9
    09-11 09:06:22.494 I/ServiceManager(  290): service 'simphonebook' died
    09-11 09:06:22.494 I/ServiceManager(  290): service 'iphonesubinfo' died
    09-11 09:06:22.494 I/ServiceManager(  290): service 'isms' died
    09-11 09:06:22.494 I/ServiceManager(  290): service 'phone' died
    09-11 09:06:22.494 I/ServiceManager(  290): service 'sip' died
    09-11 09:06:22.494 I/ServiceManager(  290): service 'isub' died
    09-11 09:06:22.514 I/ThermalEngine(  331): Sensor:tsens_tz_sensor8:75000 mC
    09-11 09:06:22.514 I/ThermalEngine(  331): Sensor:tsens_tz_sensor7:71000 mC
    09-11 09:06:22.514 I/ThermalEngine(  331): Sensor:tsens_tz_sensor6:72000 mC
    09-11 09:06:22.514 I/ThermalEngine(  331): Sensor:tsens_tz_sensor5:75000 mC
    09-11 09:06:22.534 E/BootAnimation( 3739): couldn't find audio_conf.txt
    09-11 09:06:22.545 W/BootAnimation( 3739): Audio service is not initiated.
    09-11 09:06:22.551 E/DisplayManager( 8395): Could not get display information from display manager.
    09-11 09:06:22.551 E/DisplayManager( 8395): android.os.DeadObjectException
    09-11 09:06:22.551 E/DisplayManager( 8395):     at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
    09-11 09:06:22.551 E/DisplayManager( 8395):     at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:496)
    09-11 09:06:22.551 E/DisplayManager( 8395):     at android.hardware.display.IDisplayManager$Stub$Proxy.getDisplayInfo(IDisplayManager.java:254)
    09-11 09:06:22.551 E/DisplayManager( 8395):     at android.hardware.display.DisplayManagerGlobal.getDisplayInfo(DisplayManagerGlobal.java:119)
    09-11 09:06:22.551 E/DisplayManager( 8395):     at android.view.Display.updateDisplayInfoLocked(Display.java:766)
    09-11 09:06:22.551 E/DisplayManager( 8395):     at android.view.Display.getSize(Display.java:451)
    09-11 09:06:22.551 E/DisplayManager( 8395):     at com.facebook.rti.mqtt.common.b.g.d(UserAgent.java:102)
    09-11 09:06:22.551 E/DisplayManager( 8395):     at com.facebook.rti.mqtt.common.b.g.a(UserAgent.java:53)
    09-11 09:06:22.551 E/DisplayManager( 8395):     at com.facebook.rti.mqtt.e.h.a(MqttClient.java:1294)
    09-11 09:06:22.551 E/DisplayManager( 8395):     at com.facebook.rti.mqtt.e.h.a(MqttClient.java:701)
    09-11 09:06:22.551 E/DisplayManager( 8395):     at com.facebook.rti.mqtt.e.h.s(MqttClient.java:854)
    09-11 09:06:22.551 E/DisplayManager( 8395):     at com.facebook.rti.mqtt.e.h.r(MqttClient.java:655)
    09-11 09:06:22.551 E/DisplayManager( 8395):     at com.facebook.rti.mqtt.e.h.q(MqttClient.java:535)
    09-11 09:06:22.551 E/DisplayManager( 8395):     at com.facebook.rti.mqtt.e.h.a(MqttClient.java:89)
    09-11 09:06:22.551 E/DisplayManager( 8395):     at com.facebook.rti.mqtt.e.i.run(MqttClient.java:288)
    09-11 09:06:22.551 E/DisplayManager( 8395):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
    09-11 09:06:22.554 E/QCOM PowerHAL( 3739): Failed to acquire lock.
    09-11 09:06:22.580 I/ThermalEngine(  331): Sensor:tsens_tz_sensor8:75000 mC
    09-11 09:06:22.580 I/ThermalEngine(  331): Sensor:tsens_tz_sensor7:70000 mC
    09-11 09:06:22.580 I/ThermalEngine(  331): Sensor:tsens_tz_sensor6:72000 mC
    09-11 09:06:22.580 I/ThermalEngine(  331): Sensor:tsens_tz_sensor5:74000 mC
```

please Help

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts! Have you tried [checking the logs](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/logging/info) to find out what's going on? Any hints from there?

Comment: Hi, I have added the log.

Comment: Uncheck **Avoid poor connections** under _Advanced WiFi settings_ and check if the problem persists.

Comment: I cant even find that setting

Comment: Settings > WiFi > Overflow button (3 dots ) > Advanced WiFi.

Comment: I don't have avoid poor connection option in advanced WiFi settings

Comment: It's called **Wi-Fi signal Weak** in LG G3 Uncheck that, also uncheck **Internet unavailable**. Check if the issue persists

Comment: It doesn't happen with wifi only.. My phone reboots when connecting to data network also

Comment: May be _unrelated_ but have you tried uninstalling updates for **Android System Webview**?

Comment: I tried disabling android system webview.. Still the problem is there

Comment: I have exactly the same problem but battery replacement didn't help. Reboots only when WiFi is on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After long testing and trying out all the custom roms and kernals , I gave the phone to the service center and they found the problem to be with battery due to water damage.

I have no clue why it is so , since The battery was giving me easily 1 day charge.
I replaced the battery and now its not getting restarted .

Thanks everyone for the help and suggestions.

Comment: Didn't help for me (swapped to brand new LG battery)

Comment: Do check custom roms.